# htaccess redirect with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Looking to redirect a page with 2 parameters what i have is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]&)*id=8(&|$)

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&]&)*date=1349996400(&|$)

RewriteRule ^/calendar/event\.php$ /news/nrsc-chloramines-open-house/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get rid of the leading slash in the regex. URI's sent through rewrite rules in an htaccess file have the leading slash stripped off. Also, you can make the beginning boundary match of the query string a little better:

```
#                             v--- make it match beginning or &
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=8(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)date=1349996400(&|$)
#             v---- make optional
RewriteRule ^/?calendar/event\.php$ /news/nrsc-chloramines-open-house/ [R=301,L]
```